# TYPO3 4.7.0 update, BE page temporary unavailable

Tags: connection, typo3, backend, updates

I have just updated a site to TYPO3 v. 4.7.0 but now I get a "Page
temporary unavailable" / Connection error when I click anything in the
menu in the backend and it just keeps "looking" for a page.

Have anyone else experienced this issue?

There is no problem with the FE.

Comment: Did you run all upgrade wizards, and DB compare in Install Tool?

Comment: I did! Everything went smoothly.

Comment: Please delete all `typo3temp\*` and `typo3conf\temp_*` files and folders. In backend hit clear all caches.

Comment: If this does not work, enable verbose error logging in `Install Tool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this - updated to a newer TYPO3 version and the problem was solved